# Getting unnecessary error while performing a DB operation in phonegap

Tags: android, sql, cordova

I am performing some DB(SQL) operation in Android using phonegap... Although everything is working fine but then also i am getting unnecessary error while the query executes..This is my code

```
var db = window.openDatabase("something", "1.0",
                            "PhoneGap Demo", 0);
                    db.transaction(someFunction, errorCB);

function someFunction(tx) {

    tx.executeSql('SELECT md5_value from md5_table where category = 1', [],
            gettingMd5QuerySuccess, errorCB);

}

function gettingMd5QuerySuccess(tx, results) {

        tx.executeSql('UPDATE md5_table set md5_value = "' + tempValue
            + '" where category = 1', successCB, errorCB);

    }

function errorCB(err) {
    alert("Error processing SQL: " + err);
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: what error are you getting paste it, this would help us to understand the problem better.

Comment: I am getting no error.... It is updating the table but i am getting the alert as it is going to error function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was doing a syntax error... 
I need to replace

```
tx.executeSql('UPDATE md5_table set md5_value = "' + tempValue
        + '" where category = 1', successCB, errorCB);
```

By

```
tx.executeSql('UPDATE md5_table set md5_value = "' + tempValue
        + '" where category = 1', [], successCB, errorCB);
```